# How to inject ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITION from app to framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

We have an app that has some Conditional compilation macros, for example `APP_STORE_BUILD`.

Also, We have created multiple frameworks for say multiple modules. We want to inject/share all conditional compilation macros from the app to the framework.

Right now, We are instantiating the framework based on conditional macro from the app, but overhead with this approach is that a lot of unnecessary code is getting compiled even though they aren't really needed.

```
#if APP_STORE_BUILD
   Framework.initialize(isDebug: false)
#else
   Framework.initailize(isDebug: true)
#endif
```

Issue with this approach is, Let's say we have some code in framework as follows:

```
if FrameworkManager.shared.debug
   doSomethingForDebug()
else
   doSomethingForProd()
```

Both the statements will be compile whether it is debug build or not.

I was wondering if there is a way to inject conditional compilation macros from the app to the framework, so that I can use it like this in framework

```
#if APP_STORE_BUILD
   doSomethingForProd()
#else
   doSomethingForProd()
#endif
```